# Vite.js plugin to export SVG

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I am trying to create a plugin for Vite.js & Vue.js 2.7.x to import SVG files in my project. I want Vite to import them as `.vue` components and not as static assets. Existing Vite plugin (`vite-svg-loader`) does not support Vue.js 2.x.x

My **Component.vue** imports and utilizes an SVG file as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-icon/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyIcon from "@some_path/my-icon.svg";

export default {
    components: {
        MyIcon
    }
};
</script>
```

My Vite plugin currently contains this code:

```
function svgLoader() {
    return {
        name: "svg-loader",

        load: function(id) {
            console.log(id);

            /* Some logic here to convert SVGs into Vue components */
        }
    }
}
```

`console.log(id)` produces paths to `html`, `scss`, `vue` and `js` files only. I think Vite treats SVG files as static assets, it simply copies them to the `assets` folder as follows: `assets/my-icon.7f263221.svg`. What can I do to get SVG files in my `load` function?

Comment: `does not support Vue.js 2.x` is Vue.js 3.x not an option?

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately, Vue.js 3 does not work in my app environment (there are some technical limitations). I have to use Vue.js 2 still.

Comment: maybe analyse how `vite-svg-loader` uses the `compiler-sfc` and look at using `https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/main/packages/compiler-sfc` - after all, compiler-sfc for vue2 exports `compileTemplate`

Comment: interestingly ... was looking for something completely different and found [vite-plugin-vue2-svg](https://github.com/pakholeung37/vite-plugin-vue2-svg)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you, it seems to work. It still saves SVG files in the assets folder though, not sure if it's possible to disable somehow.

Comment: not sure ... maybe read the code? it may need them there